# Dynamic composition reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way of composition of dynamic component? For example, lets say I would a have a `ListItems` component that display its children in rows. But i want to reuse some of its behavior and I would like to to something like that:

```
<ListItems rowComponent="CarsItem" headerComponent="CarsHeader"/>
```

or

```
<ListItems rowComponent="BikesItem" headerComponent="BikesHeader"/>
```

How can I achieve such abstraction?

Somethin like that did not work

```
    render:function(){
      return (
<this.props.header/>
<this.props.body/>

    )
    }
```

Comment: Your example is already an acceptable solution in itself. Just replace the string with the actual component class and you're good, i.e. `<ListItems rowComponent={BikesItem}/>`

Comment: I agree with Eelke then the only obstacle is how you load you modules.

Comment: How would the render look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make sure you declare the class that's used for the children first, you can do something like this:

```js
<ListItems rowComponent={BikesItem}/>
```

and then in your render method:

```js
render() {
    var Row = this.props.rowComponent;
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.items.map(function(item) {
                return <Row item={item}/>;
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worth mentioning additionally that in `var Row` the variable name **must** have the first letter capitalized.

Comment: mentioned here in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html, "React's JSX uses the upper vs. lower case convention to distinguish between local component classes and HTML tags"

Comment: I know. I mean it could be helpful for the OP who does not know that and may give an arbitrary name to the variable that does not follow the convention.

Comment: The doc reference was meant as an addition, sorry if that wasn't clear :)